# append parameter in URL into value of input field javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, bit.ly

I'm attempting to use javascript to modify the url on page. This URL is then being passed into the bit.ly bookmarklet to be shortened. My script will append a parameter to the URL and insert it into the URL field of the bit.ly bookmarklet. If this works i would combine the code of the bit.ly bookmarklet with the script to automatically perform its task.

**The process is as follows:**

Run bit.ly bookmarklet, run my script to append parameter, use bit.ly bookmarklet

**Source of bit.ly bookmarklet**

```
<div id="mainUnAuthShortenContainer" class="inputBoxContainer">
<input tabindex="1" id="shortenUnAuthContainer" name="url" value="https://www.google.com/" type="text">
</div>
```

**My script**

```
var elem = document.getElementById("shortenUnAuthContainer");
elem.value = window.location + "?Parameter";
```

My script works in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDvQg/1/) but not in real application. It does nothing when applied to the actual bit.ly bookmarklet. Any help is appreciated.

[The bit.ly bookmarklet](http://stoweboyd.com/post/24016133743/the-original-bitly-javascript-bookmarklet) for reference.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible.

Reason: accessing element in iframe(the URL inner iframe is different with parent window) is deny by browser.

More: You are trying to access a element which is not yet create, the time JS/iframe/element are still on loading. if you solve this problem, then you will still met the limitation above..

*I checked bitly API documentation, there is a solution may works if you have a PHP server - deploy you own bitly service: https://code.google.com/p/bitly/

FYI, bitly code lib: http://dev.bitly.com/code_libraries.html

Comment: That was my alternative solution was to use the bit.ly API. Thank you so much for responding!